# Examples / documentation for using Spring AMQP with RabbitMQ over SSL

Tags: spring-amqp

I would like to know about the documentation / API / examples for using spring AMQP for RabbitMQ over SSL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply configure the rabbit client connection factory [as shown in the rabbit documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html) and then inject that connection factory into the Spring AMQP connection factory [as described in the Spring AMQP documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.3.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/amqp.html#d4e347).